# Kubernetes - update existing configmap from file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap

1. I created a simple text file on my local machine
2. I created a configmap out of that test file:
   kubectl create configmap test-configm --from-file=test-file.txt
3. I added the volumemounts and volume to my deployment and verified the file is in my pods.

Now I want to modify the test-file.txt on my local machine and then update the configmap I created in step 2 so that all my pods can get the new version of that file, how can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/ mounted configMaps are updated automatically. You would simply have to update the configMap using a dry-run followed by imperative command like this.

```
kubectl create configmap test-configm --from-file=test-file.txt --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I was able to update my configmap no problem with your answer.  One thing I did needed to do was delete the pod / have it be recreated for the file to be updated in the pod.  Is there a way for a pod to automatically get the file updated without it being recreated?  Or would I be looking at using something like NFS instead of configmaps?

Comment: @johnb928 No matter what you have to restart your pod to take effect of changes made on configMap

Comment: Please check your cluster configuration, you should not have to recrete the Pods. Total delay from the moment when the ConfigMap is updated to the moment when new keys are projected to the Pod can be as long as the kubelet sync period + (any applicable) cache propagation delay. The sync period is by default 1 minute. Check the kubelet configuration on the cluster. I would caution you if you chose to tweak that number. It will cause overhead with frequent attempts to sync.

Comment: @VanithaKumar so I made a new set of changes and applied them.  I waited over an hour, periodically checking to see if the file in the pod updated without me needing to recreate the pod, but unfortunately the file doesn't change it seems.  This is a default kubernetes cluster from GKE.

Comment: Are you using subPath? If you can post YAML, that would help.